# CSS Media query is not working in safari browser

Tags: css, reactjs, safari, responsive-design, media-queries

I am making one project to react js and CSS. For making it responsive I am using the media query.
But after adding all the CSS and media query the media query is not working in the safari browser of phone and pc. Please, anyone, help me or suggest me how can I fix this issue.

Comment: Please include your current media query code that works on other browsers but not safari.

Comment: `@media screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
  center {
    margin-top: 0% !important;
    width: 394px;
  }
  .panel{
    width: 100%;
  }
  .shapeTriangle{
    margin-left: 99.8%;
  }
 
}`

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

Comment: It is not working, I have already added all the media queries but still, I am facing the same issue.